# negative cauchy function

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

[image]

attempt:

from defn of uniformally continuous $\forall \epsilon > 0 $ $\exists \delta > 0 $ s.t. $|x-y| < \delta $ with $x,y \in (-\infty,0)$ $\implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. My idea was to choose $x = {x_n}, y = y_m$ so that $x_n,y_m < 0$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n = \lim_{m\to \infty} y_m = 0$ i.e. for some $m,n > K \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $|x_n - y_m| < \delta$ which implies (as $f$ is uniformally continuous) $|f(x_n) - f(y_m) |< \epsilon$ so $\{f(x_n)\}$ is Cauchy, therefore converges by Cauchy's Principle.

I'm not really sure how to formalise this idea, or if it's even correct, any help please!

Comment: Why just don't take $x_n$ cauchy, $|x_n-x_m|<\delta$ $|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|<\epsilon$ and then $y_n=f(x_n)$ is cauchy?

Comment: @rlartiga is there anything wrong with the proof I have given?

Comment: You prove  $|f(x_n)−f(y_m)|<\epsilon$ and said $x_n$ is Cauchy. That's not the cauchy definition.

Comment: @rlartiga I said $f(x_n)$ is Cauchy. How is that not the definition? Could you perhaps write out a full proof for your comment, as I can't tie it together.

Comment: Ok see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First uniform continuity tells you taking $\epsilon>0  \ \exists \delta>0$:

$$|x-y| < \delta  \ x,y \in (-\infty,0) \Rightarrow  |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$$

Second take your cauchy sequence $x_n$ convergent to $0$.  How is Cauchy:
$$\forall \varepsilon>0 \ \exists M>0 \ \forall n,m\geq M: \ \ |x_n-x_m|<\epsilon$$

In the definition of cauchy take $\varepsilon=\delta$ then exists $M>0$:
$$|x_n-x_m|<\varepsilon=\delta  \ \ \forall n,m\geq M \Rightarrow |f(x_n) - f(x_m)| < \epsilon \ \forall n,m\geq M  $$

Then $f(x_n)$ is Cauchy and therefore converges.

Comment: that helped, thanks!

Comment: you are welcome